# How to prevent Hibernate from calling default constructor when resolving the unsaved-value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate 4.1.6.Final and noticed, during startup the constructor of every entity is invoked. The `EntityManager` instantiates every class marked with `@Entity` as a test, to get the `unsavedValue` identifier. I am using Hibernate without a mapping file, using only annotations. Is it possible to prevent hibernate from instantiating each entity once, may be with a predefined identifier in an annotation?

Example:
A simple class that serves as an entity to save with hibernate.

```
@Entity
public class SimpleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id = null;

    public SimpleEntity() {
        System.out.println("called constructor");
    }
}
```

The call to create an EntityManagerFactory, where the object is constructed:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hsqldb-ds");
    return emf;
}
```

Now calling:

```
EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```

Already generates the console output:
   called constructor

Comment: Why does this matter? I can't see how it would have a negative effect unless you have something going on in the constructor.

Comment: Something that probably shouldn't be in the entity constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to worry about those objects being created on startup. Creating an object takes around 100 ns, so if you have 100 entities (reasonable medium-size enterprise application), this process will still take around 10 microseconds (0.01 ms).
This is insignificant compared to how much it takes to run a trivial database query (e.g. 0.1-10 ms) or a more complex query (e.g. 100-1000 ms).

The only workarounds are:

1. You switch to an assigned identifier:

   ```
   @Id
   private Long id = null;
   ```
2. You use HBM XML mappings (there's no `unsaved-value` annotation equivalent):

   ```
   <id name="id" type="Long" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
       <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
   ```

Comment: Your first answer works in my case, of course now the `id` needs to be set manually. The question was more about this unexpected behavior itself, as it surprised me.

Comment: Hibernate must know what value to compare against when deciding if an entity is transient or detached. Without the `unsaved-value`, it would need a SELECT query to know if there's a mirroring table row for an in-memory managed entity.